# Localizer dependency Injection without constructor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm creating custom Authorization in .net core. Everything is working completely fine but I want to add localizer in attribute response.

Below is my code

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class CustomAuthorizeFilters : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public CustomAuthorizeFilters()
        { }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var User = context.HttpContext.User;

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return;

            using (var account_help = new AccountHelpers(Startup.ConnectionString))
            {
                var userId = Guid.Parse(new security.AesAlgoridhm().Decrypt(User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sid)?.FirstOrDefault().Value));
                ProfileResponse user = new ProfileResponse();

                if (user == null)
                    context.Result = new CustomResultFilters("error_access_token_expired", 401);

                if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
                    context.Result = new CustomResultFilters("bad_response_account_not_confirmed", 400);

                if (!user.Active)
                    context.Result = new CustomResultFilters("bad_response_account_inactive", 400);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried passing localizer in the constructor like this but when I'm passing an argument from the controller it is giving me error as

> attribute constructor parameter has type which is not a valid attribute parameter type

```cs
  IStringLocalizer<dynamic> localize { get; set; }
  public CustomAuthorizeFilters(IStringLocalizer<dynamic> localizer = null)
  {
            localize = localizer;
  }
```

I know attribute only supports primitive datatypes that's why I've also tried injecting direct dependency as

```
context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IStringLocalizer<dynamic>));
```

but that is giving error as:

> cannot convert from object to localizer.

Comment: You can't use dynamic as type parameter. The string localizer requires a **TYPE**. The type is used to locate the resource file containing the translations, i.e. `IStringLocalizer<MyController>` will look for a resource file named `MyController.xx-yy.resx`. If you want a shared localization resource, use a fixed class or dummy class, such as `IStringLocalizer<SharedResources>` where `SharedResources` is just an empty class `public class SharedResources { }`

Comment: Also see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#servicefilterattribute) on how to do dependency injection into attributes using the `ServiceFilter` attribute

Comment: you could try define the localizer string in shared resource, and pass `SharedResource`, refer [Make the app's content localizable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#make-the-apps-content-localizable)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#code-try-3) resources and get localizer like this

```
Type localizerType = typeof(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>);
IStringLocalizer localizer = (IStringLocalizer)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(localizerType );
```

Or if you are using resources per controller you can get controller type from `context` and get controller localizer

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    //..
    Type localizerType = GetLocalizerType(context);
    IStringLocalizer localizer = (IStringLocalizer)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(localizerType);
    //..
}

private Type GetLocalizerType(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var controllerType = (context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor).ControllerTypeInfo;
    return typeof(IStringLocalizer<>).MakeGenericType(controllerType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.